# Пункты меню пробивают сквозь диалоговое окно

Tags: html, css

Пункты меню, причём разные по типу (div, button) вылазят поверх всплывающего диалогового окна. Пробивают только пункты меню, всё остальное "сидит" под всплывающим окном:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Причём их можно даже выбрать:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```css
dialog {
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
  width: 300px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  border-radius: 5px;
}

nav {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  text-align: center;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.topmenu>li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 20px;
  position: relative;
}

.topmenu>li:last-child {
  margin-right: 0;
}

.topmenu button {
  background-color: inherit;
  float: left;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 10px 10px;
  transition: 0.5s linear;
  font-family: "Times New Roman";
  font-size: 16;
}

.topmenu button:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

.topmenu div {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  padding: 10px 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
  outline: none;
  transition: .5s linear;
}

.topmenu div:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

.fa {
  color: inherit;
  padding-left: 10px;
}

.submenu {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 10;
  -webkit-transition: 0.5s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: 0.5s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: 0.5s ease-in-out;
  transition: 0.5s ease-in-out;
}

.submenu button {
  width: 100%
}

.menu-bar ul {
  background: #f1f1f1;
}

.menu-bar ul a {
  color: #000000;
}

.menu-bar .submenu {
  display: none;
  background: #c0c0c0;
}

.menu-bar ul li:hover .submenu {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head><meta charset="utf-8"><title>dialog</title></head> 
   <body> 
  <dialog>
     <p>Полинезийцы называют Млечный путь Манго-Роа-И-Ата, что в переводе с маори означает «Длинная акула на рассвете».</p>
     <p><input type="text" name="some_text" id="some_text"></p>
     <p><button onclick="document.querySelector('dialog').close();">Закрыть окно</button></p>
  </dialog>
  <nav class="menu-bar">
     <p style="color: green">Некоторый текст</p>
     <ul class="topmenu">
           <li><button  onclick="document.querySelector('dialog').show();">Окно</button></li>
           <li><div>Меню1</div><ul class="submenu">
              <li><button type="submit" name="do_create">Пункт002</button></li>
              <li><button type="submit" name="do_paint">Пункт003</button></li>
           </ul></li>
           <li><div>Меню2</div><ul class="submenu">
              <li><button type='button'>Пункт004</button><li>
              <li><button type='button'>Пункт005</button><li>
              <li><button type='button'>Пункт006</button><li>
              <li><button type='button'>Пункт007</button><li>
            </ul></li>
           <li><button type="submit" name="do_export">МенюN</button></li>

           <li><div>Меню3</div><ul class="submenu">
              <li><button type="submit" name="do_show">Пункт1</button></li>
              <li><button type="submit" name="do_show">Пункт2</button></li>
              <li><button type="submit" name="do_show">Пункт3</button></li>
              <li><button type="submit" name="do_show">Пункт4</button></li>      
           </ul></li>

           <li><div>Меню4</div><ul class="submenu">
              <li><button type="submit" name="do_show">Пункт01</button></li>
              <li><button type="submit" name="do_show">Пункт02</button></li>
              <li><button type="submit" name="do_show">Пункт03</button></li>
              <li><button type="submit" name="do_tune">Пункт04</button></li>
           </ul></li>
           <li><button>Меню5</button></li>
           <li><button>Меню6</button></li>
        </ul>
  </nav>
   </body> 
</html>
```

Как исправить, и, по возможности, сделать, чтобы вообще при всплытии диалогового окна блокировалось всё что под ним, то есть всё на странице, кроме всплывающего окна?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Задайте z-index окну побольше. Например: `z-index: 9999;`

Примерно так я понял, что вы хотели (нажмите на модальное окно, чтоб появилось):

```css
dialog {
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
  width: 300px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  border-radius: 5px;
}

nav {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  text-align: center;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.topmenu>li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 20px;
  position: relative;
}

.topmenu>li:last-child {
  margin-right: 0;
}

.topmenu button {
  background-color: inherit;
  float: left;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 10px 10px;
  transition: 0.5s linear;
  font-family: "Times New Roman";
  font-size: 16;
}

.topmenu button:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

.topmenu div {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  padding: 10px 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
  outline: none;
  transition: .5s linear;
}

.topmenu div:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

.fa {
  color: inherit;
  padding-left: 10px;
}

.submenu {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 10;
  -webkit-transition: 0.5s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: 0.5s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: 0.5s ease-in-out;
  transition: 0.5s ease-in-out;
}

.submenu button {
  width: 100%
}

.menu-bar ul {
  background: #f1f1f1;
}

.menu-bar ul a {
  color: #000000;
}

.menu-bar .submenu {
  display: none;
  background: #c0c0c0;
}

.menu-bar ul li:hover .submenu {
  display: block;
}

dialog[open] {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    border: none;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    z-index: 9999;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

dialog[open] .info {
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
    width: 300px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    border-radius: 5px;
    display: block;
    position: static;
    height: -webkit-fit-content;
    color: black;
    padding: 1em;
    background: white;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head><meta charset="utf-8"><title>dialog</title></head> 
   <body> 
  <dialog><div class="info">
     <p>Полинезийцы называют Млечный путь Манго-Роа-И-Ата, что в переводе с маори означает «Длинная акула на рассвете».</p>
     <p><input type="text" name="some_text" id="some_text"></p>
     <p><button onclick="document.querySelector('dialog').close();">Закрыть окно</button></p>
  </div></dialog>
  <nav class="menu-bar">
     <p style="color: green">Некоторый текст</p>
     <ul class="topmenu">
           <li><button  onclick="document.querySelector('dialog').show();">Окно</button></li>
           <li><div>Меню1</div><ul class="submenu">
              <li><button type="submit" name="do_create">Пункт002</button></li>
              <li><button type="submit" name="do_paint">Пункт003</button></li>
           </ul></li>
           <li><div>Меню2</div><ul class="submenu">
              <li><button type='button'>Пункт004</button><li>
              <li><button type='button'>Пункт005</button><li>
              <li><button type='button'>Пункт006</button><li>
              <li><button type='button'>Пункт007</button><li>
            </ul></li>
           <li><button type="submit" name="do_export">МенюN</button></li>

           <li><div>Меню3</div><ul class="submenu">
              <li><button type="submit" name="do_show">Пункт1</button></li>
              <li><button type="submit" name="do_show">Пункт2</button></li>
              <li><button type="submit" name="do_show">Пункт3</button></li>
              <li><button type="submit" name="do_show">Пункт4</button></li>      
           </ul></li>

           <li><div>Меню4</div><ul class="submenu">
              <li><button type="submit" name="do_show">Пункт01</button></li>
              <li><button type="submit" name="do_show">Пункт02</button></li>
              <li><button type="submit" name="do_show">Пункт03</button></li>
              <li><button type="submit" name="do_tune">Пункт04</button></li>
           </ul></li>
           <li><button>Меню5</button></li>
           <li><button>Меню6</button></li>
        </ul>
  </nav>
   </body> 
</html>
```

Comment: Спасибо большое) Не знаю, кому теперь из Вас присудить правильный ответ

Comment: @Pavel Sumarokov У вас код в песочнице не работает.

Comment: ссылку на сайт можете прислать.

Comment: Я вылечил сниппет. Теперь всё работает)

Comment: @Pavel Sumarokov через несколько минут пришлю новый ответ.

Answer (score 3):

Я так понимаю, что для данного окна используется тег `dialog`, если да, то добавьте в CSS свойство `z-index: 9999;`

Подробнее: [z-index | htmlbook.ru](http://htmlbook.ru/css/z-index)

Comment: Спасибо большое) Не знаю, кому теперь из Вас присудить правильный ответ

Comment: Честнее будет отдать голос @VladimirRodichev, он первый ответил

Comment: Хорошо. Спасибо Вам за ответ в любом случае. Вы поступаете благородно)

Comment: @CbIPoK2513 я не против, чтобы поставили тебе. Это несложный ответ.